# Best way to check several conditions on a Textbox.Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm done with my current project and currently trying to improve the code itself.

In the app I developped, when the user clicks the "print" button, the different text in the textboxes are verified for things like is it null or empty ? is it numeric ?

My problem is that I end up with monster lines of code like

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxNbPieces.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxNbLotTrempe.Text) && !int.TryParse(textBoxNbPieces.Text, out numero) && !int.TryParse(textBoxNbLotTrempe.Text, out numero))
        {
            if (int.Parse(textBoxNbPieces.Text) < int.Parse(textBoxNbLotTrempe.Text))
            {
                erreur++;
            }
        }
```

How could I avoid that ?

Comment: This code belongs in a method that takes a TextBox argument.  No longer monster and you'll discover goodies like calling Focus() and SelectAll() and ErrorProvider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont need to check `IsNullOrEmpty` and also `int.TryParse`, the latter includes the former.

```
bool valid = int.TryParse(textBoxNbPieces.Text, out int pieces)
          && int.TryParse(textBoxNbLotTrempe.Text, out int trempe) 
          && pieces >= trempe;
if(!valid) erreur++;
```

[disclaimer: C#7 syntax]

Comment: upped this answer because of using a separate variable.